# How do applicative functors tie in with parallelizing algorithms? (Scala and Scalaz)

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, monads, functor, applicative

From Josh Suereth's "Scala in Depth":

"Applicative functors provide a way to take two computations and join them together using a function. The Traversable example highlights how two collections can be parallelized into pairs. Applicative functors and parallel processing go together like bread and butter."

I have a vague idea of the whole functors/monads/applicative stuff, but not exactly a strong grasp of it (new to the whole monad, functor stuff). I understand a bit of the concept of monads (flatten, flatMap) and monadic workflow, and functors (maps).

Can anyone please elaborate for me in terms of how it's done, examples, and/or benefits of it versus "traditional" parallelization?

Comment: I have an example in [my slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1iiTmrGkc7lZHcrgQOQ1xfro82BvFOqoVSnhH-HdWPx4/present#slide=id.p)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I forwarded the question to Josh Suereth. This is his reply:

Mike -

> I don't have a lot of time to respond, but I'll offer to examples of
>   what I mean:
>
> Example #1 - Form Validation.
>
> I want to run some validation against input and aggregate *all* the
>   errors, i.e. detect them in *parallel*.  With applicative functions I
>   can do so.
>
> So, given a set of "processing" functions, like so:
>
> ```
> def processUser(data: Data): Validation[User] = {
>   if (data get "username" isEmpty) Failure("username must not be empty")
>   else {  
>      val Some(user) = data get "username"
>      if (user contains badCharacterRegex) Failure(s"username must not contain one of ${badchars}")
>      else Success(user)
>   }
> }
> def processCreditCard(data: Data): Validation[CreditCard] = ...
> def processAddress(data: Data): Validation[Address] = ...
>
> def handleForm(data: Data): ??? = {
>   (processUser(data), processCreditCard(data), processAddress(data)) map { (user, card, address) =>
>     postPayment(user, address, card)
>   } recover {   (errors) =>
>      errors foreach println
>   }
> ```
>
> Now handle form will print out errors with CreditCard/username +
>   address all at the same time, since you've combined them using an
>   applicative functor.  That's parallel error reporting (although
>   testing isn't actually done in parallel).
>
> (2) Futures
>
> I want to do a few things in parallel and combine results.   Future's
>   "zip" method is actually an applicative functor in disguise.  I can do
>   this:
>
> ```
> Future(computation1) zip Future(computation2) map { case (one,two) => .... }
> ```
>
> I've just used Applicative Functors to "join" parallel computations.
>   It's exactly the same as the Form validation example.
>
> Hope that helps!
>   - Josh

(note these code snippets are non-compilable examples; I was using SBT's applicative syntax with the concepts in Scalaz, so you need to choose a library to use applicatives and what they are applying onto)

Comment: I tried the (processX, processY, processZ) map { (x, y, z) => ... } but it doesn't compile for me. Is it a feature of scalaz7 to have this mapping of TupleX[Validation, ...]?

Comment: I don't think Josh was referring to scalaz at all. I'll point him to this thread.

Comment: Yeah, my post is more basic, not specific to Scalaz.  I was using SBT's applicative syntax with the concepts in Scalaz.   Here's a decent introductoin: https://github.com/bartschuller/scalaz-validation-example